# CSS flexbox layout scales wrong with scrollbars

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I try to create this layout:

```css
.wrapper,
html,
body {
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
}

.wrapper {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

header {
  background-color: red;
}

footer {
  background-color: green;
}

#content_row {
  flex: 2;
  display: flex;
}

#left {
  background-color: yellow;
  flex: 1 1 auto;
}

#middle {
  background-color: orange;
  flex: 0 0 auto;
  min-width: 400px;
}

#right {
  background-color: purple;
  flex: 1 1 auto;
}

#content {
  margin: 10px;
  background-color: white;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div class="wrapper">
    <header>header_row</header>
    <div id="content_row">
      <div id="left"> </div>
      <div id="middle">
        <p>Title
        </p>
        <div id="content">
          <p style="white-space: pre-line;">Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. Vestibulum tortor quam, feugiat vitae, ultricies eget, tempor sit amet, ante. Donec eu libero sit amet quam egestas semper. Aenean ultricies mi vitae
            est. </p>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div id="right"></div>
    </div>
    <footer>footer_row</footer>
  </div>
</body>
```

https://codepen.io/joerno/pen/JWrwpr

[image]

My first problem is to have a 100% height of the white area.

My second problem are the scrollbars. The size of the white-section can increase, so the left (yellow) and right area (purple) divs are shrinking. It works so far, but if the white area is getting wider (or you scale down the window width), the header and footer are not scaled too:

[image]

At least the heigth is also a problem:

[image]

Any idea? Thanks in advance...

Comment: You can hide the scrollbars using `overflow:hidden;`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Use the `overflow` property on the right containers to create horizontal and vertical scrollbars.
- To give your paragraph (white background) full height, make the parent a flex container. This activates the `align-items: stretch` default, which tells flex items to consume all available cross-axis space (height, in this case).
- Percentage heights are tricky and bloat your code. You can achieve the same effect with simply `height: 100vh`.

```css
.wrapper, html, body {
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
}

.wrapper {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

header {
  background-color: red;
}

footer {
  background-color: green;
}

#content_row {
  flex: 2;
  display: flex;
  overflow: auto;             /* new */
}

#left {
  background-color: yellow;
  flex: 1 1 auto;
}

#middle {
  background-color: orange;
  flex: 0 0 auto;
  min-width: 400px;
  display: flex;              /* new */
  flex-direction: column;     /* new */
}

#right {
  background-color: purple;
  flex: 1 1 auto;
}

#content {
  margin: 10px;
  background-color: white;
  flex: 1;                     /* new */
  display: flex;               /* new */
  overflow: auto;              /* new */
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <header>header_row</header>
  <div id="content_row">
    <div id="left"> </div>
    <div id="middle">
      <p>Title
      </p>
      <div id="content">
        <p style="white-space: pre-line;">
          DonecDonecDonecDonecDonecDonecDonecDonecDonecDonecDonecDonecDonecDonecDonecDonecDonecDonecDonecDonecDonecDonecDonecDonecDonecDonecDonecDonecPellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. Vestibulum tortor
          quam, feugiat vitae, ultricies eget, tempor sit amet, ante. Donec eu libero sit amet quam egestas semper. et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. Vestibulum tortor quam, feugiat vitae, ultricies eget, tempor sit amet, ante. Donec eu libet
          netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. Vestibulum tortor quam, feugiat vitae, ultricies eget, tempor sit amet, ante. Donec eu libet netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. Vestibulum tortor quam, feugiat vitae, ultricies eget, tempor
          sit amet, ante. Donec eu libet netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. Vestibulum tortor quam, feugiat vitae, ultricies eget, tempor sit amet, ante. Donec eu libet netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. et netus et malesuada fames ac
          turpis egestas. Vestibulum tortor quam, feugiat vitae, ultricies eget, tempor sit amet, ante. Donec eu libet netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. Vestibulum tortor quam, feugiat vitae, ultricies eget, tempor sit amet, ante. Donec eu libet
          netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. Vestibulum tortor quam, feugiat vitae, ultricies eget, tempor sit amet, ante. Donec eu lib Vestibulum tortor quam, feugiat vitae, ultricies eget, tempor sit amet, ante. Donec eu lib Aenean ultricies
          mi vitae est. </p>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div id="right"></div>
  </div>
  <footer>footer_row</footer>
</div>
```

[**revised codepen**](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/MprQee)

Answer (score 0):

Here's a link for a complete guide on using flexbox:

https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/

Let me know if this is what you wanted:

```css
.wrapper, html, body {
    height:100%;
    margin:0;
}

.wrapper {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
}

header {
    background-color: red;
}

footer {
    background-color: green;
}

#content_row {   
    flex:3;
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
}
#content_row > div{
  flex-grow: 1;
}

#left {
    background-color: yellow;
}

#middle {
    background-color: orange;
}
#content_row > div{
  flex-grow: 2;
}
#content{
  height: 100%;
}
#right {
    background-color: purple;
}

#content {
    margin: 10px;
    background-color: white;    
}
```

```html
<body>
 <div class="wrapper">
    <header>header_row</header>    
    <div id="content_row">
        <div id="left"> </div>
        <div id="middle">
          <p>Title
          </p>
          <div id="content">
            <p style="white-space: pre-line;">Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. 
              Vestibulum tortor quam, feugiat vitae, ultricies eget, tempor sit amet, ante. 
              Donec eu libero sit amet quam egestas semper. 
              Aenean ultricies mi vitae est. </p>
          </div>
      </div>
        <div id="right"></div>
    </div>
    <footer>footer_row</footer>  
</div>
</body>
```

Comment: Thanks, but it's still not scrolling large content:
https://codepen.io/joerno/pen/xqPGaQ